# Install PHP 7.2.20 with LEMP stack

Tags: php, ubuntu-20.04, lemp

I am trying to install php **7.2.20** with lemp stack on ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.2
```

It installs PHP **7.2.34**

Tried google searching but no luck, anybody can point me to right direction?

_audi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Install an older version of php using apt-get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801460/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-php-using-apt-get)

Comment: No, as version 7.2.20 is nowhere to be found @lunchpad.net

Comment: The answers are about how to install a specific version in ubuntu. They arent specific to launchpad. So have you tried them?

Comment: Yes I did, but version 7.2.20 is not listed anywhere but @ https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.2.20.tar.gz

I did download from php.net compiled it then installed it.

it installed @ usr/local directory which is useless for me